# Rails edit and update actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

When I try to update a post I get the following error: "No route matches [POST] '/posts/id/edit/'".  My code pretty much matches several online tutorials.  It should update the post params and then redirect back to index. I don't know why I am getting this error?

In my controller I have,

```
def update
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        redirect_to action: :index
        flash[:notice] = 'post was updated.'
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end    

    def edit
        @post = post.find(params[:id])
    end
```

In index.html I have a button for the edit function.

```
<td><%= button_to "Edit", edit_post_path(c.id ), { :method => :get } %></td>
```

In the edit.html, I have this code.

```
<%= form_for :post do |c| %>
    <p>
    <%= c.label :post_name %><br/>
    <%= c.text_field :post_name %><br/>
    <%= c.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes for posts:

```
posts_path      GET      /posts(.:format)            posts#inde
                POST     /posts(.:format)            posts#create
new_post_path   GET      /posts/new(.:format)        posts#new
edit_post_path  GET      /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
post_path       GET      /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#show
                PATCH    /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#update
                PUT      /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#update
                DELETE   /posts/:id(.:format)        posts#destroy
```

Comment: I updated the post with the routes.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `link_to`

```
<td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(c.id ) %></td>
```

[button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) creates a form containing a single button that posts to the URL.

To use `button_to` with get (Not advised since buttons are supposed to make POST)

```
<td><%= button_to "Edit", edit_post_path(c.id ), :method => :get %></td>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the button? I have a button working just fine for delete.

Comment: The button_to and link_to work the same for me it gets to the edit page, when I hit save changes is when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra parentheses as the method is specified as an option in the fourth argument:

```
<td><%= button_to "Edit", edit_post_path(c.id ), {}, { :method => :get } %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have

```
form_for :post
```

which probably has to be

```
form_for @post
```

and since it can't understand it, it may assume that it's a new record instead of an existing one and thus automatically define a url that leads to the create action, just change `:post to @post`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving this problem. 
edit.html.erb was changed to:

```
<%= form_for :post, { :url => post_path, method => :patch } do |c| %>
    <p>
    <%= c.label :post_name %><br/>
    <%= c.text_field :post_name %><br/>
    <%= c.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

The posts controller had the following change:

```
def update
    @post = post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(params.require(:post).permit(:post_text))
        redirect_to action: :index
        flash[:notice] = 'post was updated.'
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end    

    def edit
        @post = post.find(params[:id])
    end
```